# Swift 4 add images to image array

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I have this code:

```
var imgArr: [UIImage?] = []
imgArr = [UIImage(named: "a1.jpg"), UIImage(named: "a2.jpg"), UIImage(named: "a3.jpg"), UIImage(named: "a4.jpg"), UIImage(named: "a5.jpg")] // this is files in assets



let documentsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let path = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent((AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/json/myPackageData.json") // this is json file in documents folder
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(MyPackageData.self, from: data)

                for image in jsonData.tipsSlidesSizes.keys {
                    print("<!= \(image)")
                    imgArr.append(UIImage(named: image))
                }


            } catch {
                print("ConceptGalleryView - Error 1030: Problem with parse file. \(error)")
            }

            print("Summary:")
            debugPrint(imgArr)
```

I have photo in path: Documents/myimages/......

as a result of this code I get:

```
Summary:
[Optional(<UIImage: 0x6000000b1d60>, {1000, 750}), Optional(<UIImage: 0x60c0000ae580>, {600, 630}), Optional(<UIImage: 0x60c0000aeb80>, {1537, 1080}), Optional(<UIImage: 0x60c0000aedc0>, {1035, 1608}), Optional(<UIImage: 0x6080000ae5e0>, {1280, 853}), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

And the files are not visible later in the slider.

Why can not I see in the table of my photos? What's wrong with this code?

**UPDATE CODE**

OK, I'm trying update my code with yours suggestion:

```
let documentsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let path = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent((AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/json/myPackageData.json")
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(MyPackageData.self, from: data)

                for image in jsonData.tipsSlidesSizes.keys {
                    print("<!= \(image)")
                    imgArr.append(UIImage(named: image))
                    let imgPath = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent((AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/GET_TIPS_SLIDES/")

                    let dataImg = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: imgPath.path)!)
                    if let img = UIImage(data: dataImg) {
                        imgArr.append(UIImage(named: img))
                    }

                }


            } catch {
                print("ConceptGalleryView - Error 1030: Problem with parse file. \(error)")
            }
```

but I have error in:

```
if let img = UIImage(data: dataImg) {
```

Cannot convert value of type 'NSData?' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: Try by changing imgArr declaration to var imaArr = [UIImage]()

Comment: `UIImage(named: image)` does not load images from a custom path, only when included in an assets library. otherwise you need to load them yourself.

Comment: try `imgArr.append UIImage(contentsOfFile: image))`

Comment: instead of NSData use Data

Comment: I make this: imgArr.append(UIImage(named: image))
                    let imgPath = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent((AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/image/" + image) imgArr.append (UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath.path)) - and its not workin g :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get `NSData` from your DocumentDirectory path , after that convert in to your image :

```
if let dataImg = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: "")!) {
      if let img = UIImage(data: dataImg as Data) {

      }
}
```

where **imgPath** :  your DocumentDirectory image path

Comment: I updated my code in first post. Can you check my code?